# Shortening code for formatted output

Tags: python

I must write a two dimensional array (let's say array[100][20]) into a file. This is just an example of my code:

```
for i in range(0,99):
  print >> file, "%15.9e%24.15e%3d..." % (array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2], ... )
```

Is it possible to shorten it after "%" symbol with a slicing or something similar notation?

Comment: you have not provided enough information. try to provide a sample data set, which is a smaller array, and the desired output.

Comment: @jathanism -- for input data, you could just use:  `[[0.0]*20 for _ in range(100)]`

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
print >> file, format_string % tuple(array[i])
```

That said, I think that I would probably use `numpy` here to save the data in a format that isn't ascii for efficiency (both in terms of time spent doing IO and disk space).

Comment: On why casting `array[i]` to a tuple works ([Source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)): *If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple object. [5] Otherwise, values must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary).*

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being down-voted, are you sure you're asking the right question? I've always found that if something is ugly or hard, it's probably not the best approach, especially in Python.

You might check out the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)---what format do you want to write, exactly?

There's also the [texttable](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable) module, that makes pretty tables for you, and will even dump them to a text file.

Finally, if you should be so inclined, there are the [Python Excel Utilities](http://www.python-excel.org/), which will dump things into Excel spreadsheets. I have written some wrappers around the excel read and excel write interfaces in that module that I'll post here if you want---they're nothing special, but they may save you some time.

Comment: This is a good answer.  If I used `csv` more, I might have actually thought of it and suggested it.  +1 to you.  (and, I've found that at least 9 times out of 10, suggesting a better alternative is a good idea on StackOverflow.  If you keep taking "risks" like that, you'll do just fine around here ;-)